# How to embed xmp xml metadata to PNG

Tags: java, image, png, xmp, apache-commons-io

I am using the commons io imaging library. On the [format page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/formatsupport.html) the library says

> Can read XMP XML (as as String) from TIFF, GIF, PNG, JPEG and PSD. Can
>   embed XMP XML when writing GIF, PNG and TIFF. Can remove, insert and
>   update XMP XML into existing JPEG files.

However, I can't find any example of how to embed xmp xml to a PNG image. I've been able to update xmp xml of a JPEG with the code below but not sure how to do it for PNG

```
        String xmpXml = "<x:xmpmeta>" +
        "\n<sample>" +
        "\n\t<Date>"+"some date"+"</Date>" +
        "\n\t<Description>"+"Some description"+"</Description>" +
        "\n</sample>" +
        "\n</x:xmpmeta>";
      JpegXmpRewriter rewriter = new JpegXmpRewriter();
      rewriter.updateXmpXml(isNew1,os, xmpXml);
```